# Data import via Management API successful, but data for custom dimensions does not show

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

I am trying to import data for custom dimension in Google Analytics through the .NET client library. In Google Analytics, when I view the uploads for a data set from **Admin > Data Import > Manage Uploads**, it says my uploads are successful, but the data for the custom dimension doesn't seem to show up in my report. Right now, I am just using my custom dimension to set the category for an article.

Here is how I am uploading through the .Net client library.

```cs
string accountId = "***";
string webPropertyId = "***";
string customDataSourceId = "***";
string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
IUploadProgress progress;
using (var dataStream = CreateArticleCsvStream(articles))
{
    var fs = File.Create("test.csv");
    dataStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Close();
    progress = service.Management.Uploads.UploadData(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, dataStream, contentType).Upload();
}

if (progress.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
{
    throw progress.Exception;
}
```

Here is the output for test.csv

```
ga:pagePath,ga:dimension1
/path/to/page/,"MyCategory"
```

When I download the file from the data set, I get the same file as the test.csv file, it just has a random filename that gets assisgned to it.

I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644944/data-import-via-management-api) similar to mine, but there was no solution posted. Any help would be appreciated.

I have also waited over 24 hours, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a few days of trial and error but I finally found the solution.

First thing to check is that your Website's URL is correct under **Admin > View Settings**. We had ours set up like `my.domain.com/path/to/site` when it should have just been `my.domain.com`. (We are using SharePoint, which is why `path/to/site` was appended to the site URL)

Second thing to check is that your key/pagePath entries are all correct. In our case, we had an extra forward slash at the end of the URL. For some reason, Google Analytics displays the trailing forward slash in reports, but does not actually store it for the pagePath.

Another error may be capitalization. It seems like GA applies filters after the data has been processed. If you add the lowercase/uppercase filter, notice that it only affects how the URLs display in your reports. Behind the scenes, it seems that GA still stores the URL with whatever capitalization the hit initially came in with. For example if the URL on your site is `my.domain.com/path/to/PAGE.aspx` and you apply the lowercase filter, the pagePath will display in your reports as `/path/to/page.aspx`. But, if you use the lowercase value in your csv import, **the data will not join**. You must use the pagePath that appears on your site (`/path/to/PAGE.aspx` in this case).

It would be nice if Google gave some log files when it tries to process and join the uploaded data with the existing data, rather than just saying the upload was successful even though the processing/joining stage may fail.